# Mongoengine creation_time attribute in Document

Tags: python, django, orm, mongodb, mongoengine

I am trying to add a `creation_time` attribute to my documents. The following would be an example:

```
import datetime

class MyModel(mongoengine.Document):
    creation_date = mongo.DateTimeField()
    modified_date = mongo.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

Django models have built in parameter for their `DateTimeField` objects like `add_now`, etc.,
but MongoEngine does not support this.

I am wondering if best way to do this is the following:

```
m,created = MyModel.objects.get_or_create()
if created:
    m.creation_date = datetime.datetime.now()
```

or if there is a better, nicer way.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You could override the save method.

```
class MyModel(mongoengine.Document):
    creation_date = mongo.DateTimeField()
    modified_date = mongo.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.creation_date:
            self.creation_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.modified_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        return super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I had figured out the default bit, but overriding the save method to track the modified time is perfect. Thank you :)

Comment: The problem with this though is that the save function won't be called if you do an update instead of a .save  right?

Comment: override `clean` method instead of `save` should be better, [docs here](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/document-instances.html)

Comment: The modified_date can't be updated when I use the function `update`

Answer (score 28):

As an aside, the creation time is stamped into the `_id` attribute - if you do:

```
YourObject.id.generation_time
```

Will give you a datetime stamp.

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer.  I've used `@property` on a function like this to get the created_time: `def created_at(self): return self.id.generation_time if self.id else None`

Answer (score 6):

One nice solution is reusing a single signal handler for multiple documents.

```
class User(Document):
    # other fields...
    created_at = DateTimeField(required=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    updated_at = DateTimeField(required=True)

class Post(Document):
    # other fields...
    created_at = DateTimeField(required=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    updated_at = DateTimeField(required=True)

def update_timestamp(sender, document, **kwargs):
    document.updated_at = datetime.utcnow()

signals.pre_save.connect(update_timestamp, sender=User)
signals.pre_save.connect(update_timestamp, sender=Post)
```

Be careful to assign a callable and not a fixed-value as the default, for example  `default=datetime.utcnow` without `()`. Some of the other answers on this page are incorrect and would cause `created_at` for new documents to always be set to the time your app was first loaded.

It's also always better to store UTC dates (`datetime.utcnow` instead of `datetime.now`) in your database.

Answer (score 4):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from mongoengine import *
from mongoengine import signals
from datetime import datetime

class User(Document):
    email = StringField(required=True, unique=True)
    first_name = StringField(max_length=50)
    last_name = StringField(max_length=50)
    # audit fields
    created_on = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    updated_on = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())

    @classmethod
    def pre_save(cls, sender, document, **kwargs):
        document.updated_on = datetime.now()

signals.pre_save.connect(User.pre_save, sender=User)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the timestamp field in a bunch of Documents you can keep your code [DRY](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/misc/design-philosophies/#don-t-repeat-yourself-dry) by creating an abstract Document instead.

```
from datetime import datetime
from mongoengine import Document

class CreateUpdateDocument(Document):
    meta = {
        'abstract': True
    }

    # last updated timestamp
    updated_at = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

    # timestamp of when entry was created
    created_at = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.created_at:
            self.created_at = datetime.now()
        self.updated_at = datetime.now()
        return super(CreateUpdateDocument, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: You might want to put `self.updated_at = datetime.now()` under an `else` statement, so you can keep the idea of "if the updated_at is none, that means the model was never updated".

Answer (score 4):

My preferred solution is to use the `@property` decorator to return the creation datetime as extracted from the ObjectId:

```
@property
def creation_stamp(self):
    return self.id.generation_time
```

Answer (score 1):

Try use lambda value:

```
import datetime
from mongoengine import Document

class MyModel(Document):
    creation_date = mongo.DateTimeField()
    modified_date = mongo.DateTimeField(default=lambda : datetime.datetime.now())
```

Comment: No need to use a lambda, just use `mongo.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)`

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, I've set the `creation_date` default to `datetime.now()` and then have hidden the field on the admin form so you remove the possibility of a user overwriting the correct value. That requires almost no code.

Overriding the save method as suggested by Willian is also effective since you can programmtically block any updates to the `creation_date` and update the `modfied_date` at the same time.

Comment: when you say "traditionally", do you mean using the Django ORM or MongoEngine specifically?

Answer (score -8):

You could use auto_now_add parameter as per [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField):

```
class MyModel(mongoengine.Document):
    creation_date = mongo.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    modified_date = mongo.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
```

Comment: That is most unfortunate. Then overriding the save as in the accepted answer is the right answer. I'd create a patch to add the feature though :)