# Update DateTime field in mongoengine with auto_now_add

Tags: python, fork, mongoengine

I'm trying to make [a fork](https://github.com/asfaltboy/mongoengine) of [MongoEngine](https://github.com/hmarr/mongoengine) that will allow auto updating of a `DateTimeField` based on passing True to an `auto_now` or `auto_now_add` ([a la Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add)).

So far I've added the attributes to the `__init__` method of `DateTimeField` like so:

```
def __init__(self, auto_now=None, auto_now_add=None, **kwargs):
    self.auto_now, self.auto_now_add = auto_now, auto_now_add
    super(DateTimeField, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to populate this value cleanly when a document is created/saved. The only solution I see so far, is to add field specific behavior in BaseDocument's save or validate methods... But I don't like it.

Does anyone know of a better method?

By the way: I though of having a go at this after reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8098122/484127) and @[equinoxel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/515948/equinoxel)'s comment about extending mongo and being used to this attribute in django.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could add a pre save signal and update the document date before saving.

```
class MyDoc(Document):
    name = StringField()
    updated_at = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

    @classmethod
    def pre_save(cls, sender, document, **kwargs):
        document.updated_at = datetime.datetime.now()

signals.pre_save.connect(MyDoc.pre_save, sender=MyDoc)
```

The main issues with this is they wont be updated if you call `update` or if you do bulk updates eg: `MyDocs.objects.update(set__name=X)`

Added ticket: https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/110

Comment: Thanks a lot. Although, I kind of knew I could do that (also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11851794/484127) for [the question I linked above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098122/mongoengine-creation-time-attribute-in-document) told me that) I appreciate the help. By the way, I just wanted to solve that ticket you opened and needed a push in the right direction :)

Comment: Well the question linked above overrides save which isnt great and misses the point about updates as well.  So currently you have to handle it in your app.

Comment: yea, the accepted answer does, but the one I linked to (last in question page) suggests exactly what you have here - sorry for being anal about it... Still though, any idea how to go about solving this issue? Do you think it will require a dramatic change in how mongoengine handles save/update of documents? Like for instance, running a "prepare_fields" that will run in both save & update methods of document.py?

Comment: @Dajuju update can be done with clean() that is called before saving on mongo.

Comment: It requires blinker library installed. `pip install blinker` [pypi/blinker](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blinker)

Comment: What's bad about overriding `save`?