# How change button logic on Flask Admin?

Tags: python-2.7, flask, flask-admin

I want to change logic of button on Flask-Admin. Exactly: Save button.
Save button should send request on other URL and then save response on Data Base. Can i do this? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a class that extends `flask.ext.admin.contrib.sqla.ModelView`, you can override the `on_model_change` method.

See http://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask.ext.admin.model.BaseModelView.on_model_change

For example, something like this:

```
from flask.ext.admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView

from my_app import app, db
from models import MyModel


class MyModelView(ModelView):
    ...

    def on_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):
        # Custom code to call URL
        # Custom code to save to DB
        ...

admin = Admin(app)
admin.add_view(MyModelViewView(MyModel, db.session))
```

You might also find your question has been answered here: [Customize (override) Flask-Admin's Submit method from edit view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21140030/customize-override-flask-admins-submit-method-from-edit-view)