# Flask-admin; To add custom logic during row insertion

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I'm new to the flask-admin library so please forgive me if this is trivial. When I click 'Save' to create a new row for a model, I also want to do some custom things. In my case, I'll create a table dynamically whose name is the string entered in the form. This will be in addition to what flask-admin does for me i.e. add a new row to the model table. So where will I put the custom logic to do what I want to do? I saw this post on so: [Customize (override) Flask-Admin's Submit method from edit view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21140030/customize-override-flask-admins-submit-method-from-edit-view) with Joe's answer about overriding on_model_change but I'll like some more explanation. From the docs, it says that on_model_change is called from update_model and create_model. When I click on the source link to the right, I get to: http://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/flask_admin/model/base/#BaseModelView.create_model . It doesn't show the code. So I don't know how it is implemented.
Can someone please illustrate what I'm trying to in a simple sample code? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The right way of doing this (as you have mentioned) is through `after_model_change` function. Quoting Flask-Admin source code

```
def after_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):
    """
        Perform some actions after a model was created or updated and
        committed to the database.

        Called from create_model after successful database commit.

        By default does nothing.

        :param form:
            Form used to create/update model
        :param model:
            Model that was created/updated
        :param is_created:
            True if model was created, False if model was updated
    """
    pass
```

So basically, in your case, you need to perform the table creation inside this function on your model. Namely

```
class MyModelView(BaseModelView):
     column_list = ('fieldX', 'fieldY')

     def after_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):
         tablename = form.tablename
         if is_created: # create the table just once
             perform_dynamic_table_creation(conn,tablename)
```