# TypeError: filter_by() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am following [Flask-SQLalchemy update a row's information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699360/flask-sqlalchemy-update-a-rows-information) to try to update an object in an endpoint. I have:

```
def dashboard_presave_callback(data, existing_id=None):
    # if existing_id, overwrite...else, make new item
    print(data)
    url_to = data.get('url_to', None)
    print(url_to)
    if isinstance(url_to, str):
        pass
    else:
        url_to = json.dumps(url_to)

    if existing_id:
        data.update({'id': existing_id})
        obj = DashboardItem.query.filter_by(id==existing_id).update(data)
        # obj.update(data)
    else:
        obj = DashboardItem(**data)
        DB.session.add(obj)

    DB.session.commit()



class GenericApiView(JsonApiView):


    # @jwt_required()
    def post(self, model_type):
        request_json = request.get_json()
        dashboard_presave_callback(request_json)
        return Response({'message': 'ok'}, 200)

    def put(self, model_type):
        request_json = request.get_json()
        existing_id = request_json['id']
        del request_json['id']
        dashboard_presave_callback(request_json, existing_id)
        return Response({'message': 'ok'}, 200)
```

the model looks like

```
class DashboardItem(DB.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'dashboard_item'

    id = DB.Column(DB.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_email = DB.Column(DB.String(200), unique=True, nullable=False)
    url_to = DB.Column(DB.Text)
    display_text = DB.Column(DB.String(200), nullable=False)

    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098122/mongoengine-creation-time-attribute-in-document
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('huh?')
        print(args)
        print(kwargs)
        self.url_to = 'it worked'
        return super(DashboardItem, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I'm doing it this way because my `save` didn't work, but this way is fine because I want the same behavior on `update`.

I get

```
    obj = DashboardItem.query.filter_by(id==existing_id).update(data)
TypeError: filter_by() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

it seems like I'm doing the same thing in the example. Why won't this `filter_by` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
obj = DashboardItem.query.filter_by(id=existing_id).update(data)
```

You have an extra `=` sign making it pass a boolean. 
`filter_by` is supposed to take only one argument which is of `DashboardItem.query`. You are passing this implicitly already by using `.` notation. All other arguments that you will need to provide including `id` are named arguments.

Comment: thank you. the control freaks won't let me accept answer for 10 minutes :)

Comment: haha.. no worries. you are welcome. may be later when you visit SO again, you can accept.

Comment: I guess that's a reasonable premise. Still don't understand why yall wanna prevent young people from learning (no subjective questions? no sharing of knowledge?). Is there justification for that? I have to use hashnode for most questions (thank God it came out)

Comment: I just signed up hashnode. didn't know about it. From first looks, it feels more like a blogging site about coding. From my understanding SO, is very focused as a technical help-each-other platform and hashnode looks like a quora style social network with a programmer flair.